# Setting null terminated string in environment variables via ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, environment-variables, processbuilder

As the caption states I'm trying to set an environment variable with multiple null terminated filenames.

My code looks like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(execCmd);
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.clear();
String storedFiles = "";
Iterator<Attributes> storedSequence = info.getSequence().iterator();
while (storedSequence.hasNext()) {
    storedFiles += storedSOPSequence.next().getFilename() + "\0";
}
env.put("StoredFiles", storedFiles);

try {
    pb.start();
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

But I run into the following excepion:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Invalid environment variable value: "/tmp/tmp.DXrJMdJmbW/53cd50f9"
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You probably don't need to add the nulls. They will be converted to null terminated strings when they arrive in the command you are running.

Comment: Sure? What I'm trying to achieve is a varibale which value looks like this: filename1\0filename2\0filename2\0...filenameN\0

Comment: That isn't really a good idea as the O/S may interpret the null as the end of the string. Use a different control character if you want an out-of-band separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use nulls as separators in strings, especially when passing the strings to the operating system.

The O/S interprets null as an end-of-string marker and may not copy anything after that.

Use another control character instead (e.g. '\r').

Comment: I use spaces now. the resulting string in the env variable looks now like this:
"file1" "file2" "file 3"
 Therefore i can wrap it in my called bash script like this:
NEW_ARRAY=( $variable )
 So i can easily use it as array.

 Keep in mind that any " should be escaped as \" in the Java code!